# Can you reload a file from the server in Notepad++?

Tags: ftp, notepad++

In Notepad++ I am using the NppFTP extension and would like to be able to reload the file from the server. There is an option to reload from disc, but that does not get any changes that someone else might have done to the file on the server. Right-clicking the tab and selecting "Reload" is the same as choosing "File -> Reload from disc" and this is not what I want.

You can close then reopen the file in the NppFTP window or right-click it in the NppFTP window and select "Download File", but if you are deep in the tree structure, it might take a while to find the file just for a simple "reload". I was looking for a menu option so that it can be attached to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file from a server using NPPFTP, it creates a local copy in the temporary folder. Thus if you want the updated copy (With changes from others), your only option is to close and reopen the file.

Comment: I hope this is not the only answer... but thanks for responding

Comment: The problem with this is that if you are working on a large website and you have opened a bunch of files and are not currently in the folder that the file you want to refresh is in, you have to go and hunt it down in the file tree. This can be frusterating when you have a "[root]/includes/functions/general.php" as well as a"[root]/admin/includes/functions/general.php", but are far enough down the tree that you can't see if the parent file is the base root or the root/admin...